# Why does this jquery slideToggle code not work?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am trying to alter the button text for a expand/collapse button.  Basically, a user clicks "Collapse" and I perform a slideToggle and when the slideToggle is done, I change the button text to "Expand" and vice-versa.

The following code works great however if you click the expand/collapse button rapidly, it looses its mind and shows "Expand" when it's already expanded or "Collapse" when it's already collapsed.

Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks!

function toggleBox( button, box ){
    if($(box).is(":hidden")) {
        $(box).slideToggle("slow", function(){
            $(button).html("Collapse");
        });
    }
    else {
        $(box).slideToggle("slow", function(){
            $(button).html("Expand");
        });
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, it'd be safer to do the check as you're setting the text, **after** the animation finishes, like this:

```
function toggleBox( button, box ){ 
  $(box).slideToggle("slow", function(){ 
    $(button).html($(this).is(":hidden") ? "Expand" : "Collapse"); 
  }); 
}
```

Currently you're checking when it starts, but remember it's not `:hidden` until it *finishes* hiding, so until the moment the `slideUp` completes, it's still `:visible` :)

Comment: Thanks everyone.  But Nick, your solution worked perfectly!  Much more elegant than mine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using

```
:not(:animated)
```